# Using perfmon on Jmeter - problems monitoring by process name

Tags: jmeter, perfmon

So I was running some tests across some machines and monitoring CPU/Memory usage by process.
To test it's accuracy I was also monitoring with VisualVM.
and the graphs were off slightly.
Also on Jmeter when I monitor CPU/memory but not per process name it gives the exact same results - so it's not seeing the process.
If i do it by process ID it works - but the process ID changes so don't want to go this route.

Beside process name there is occurence , anyone know what this is and whether it can be left blank or not.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I don't think the process is called `kafka`, my expectation is that both for [Windows](https://github.com/apache/kafka/blob/trunk/bin/windows/kafka-run-class.bat#L179) or for [Linux/Unix](https://github.com/apache/kafka/blob/trunk/bin/kafka-run-class.sh#L304) you should be looking for **`java` process**, not `Kafka`

[image: JMeter Kafka]

So try changing the process name to `java` and it should start working as expected:

[image]

If it doesn't - [launch PerfMon Agent with `--loglevel debug` parameter](https://github.com/undera/perfmon-agent#usage) - it should print a lot of useful information into [stdout](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Standard_streams#Standard_output_(stdout))

Just in case check out [How to Monitor Your Server Health & Performance During a JMeter Load Test](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/how-monitor-your-server-health-performance-during-jmeter-load-test) article for more information.

Comment: Thanks, but according to VisualVM the process is called "Kafka" and I get the same for other processes like logstash and elasticsearch  https://c2.staticflickr.com/2/1934/31743804788_ae7afe55d5_b.jpg

Comment: From operating system perspective it is `java`, if you want to plot VisualVM-style metrics you can consider going for [JMXMon Sample Collector](https://jmeter-plugins.org/wiki/JMXMon/). You can install JMXMon using [JMeter Plugins Manager](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/how-install-jmeter-plugins-manager)

Comment: OK thanks, so that needs to be installed on all machines im monitoring - like the jmeter agent ? or does this plugin only need to be installed where Jmeter is running ?